# Image set to absolute is out of alignment = not inside parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem i was hopeing you guys could help with. I have create an empty white box on my frontimage. To do that i have to change the image to absolute. After this, the image is now out of alignment. To make it easier to understand, there are two images i want to show you, so you can see the problem.

**Image when it is set to Relative:**

[image]

Its the water image in top.. here you see that it is perfect align (left and right side) with the aque color boxes under.

**Image when it is set to Absolute:**

[image]

Somehow when i set the image to absolute, it gets bigger in the right side. I have read some earlier post that the parant should be set to relative.. I mean that I already have done that.

**Code:**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 contentpage">

        <img id="frontimage" src="~/images/index.jpg" />


    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="bookingbox">

        </div>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
#frontimage{
z-index: 1;
position: absolute;
}

.contentpage {
height: 650px;
background-color: white;
position: absolute;
}

.bookingbox {
background-color: green;
position: absolute;
height: 450px;
width: 300px;
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
top: 30px;
left: 30px;    
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Now it works.. take a look at the picture :D

[image]

Comment: Of course it's out of alignment! When you set the image to absolute, it breaks off the flow of the page, and basically creates a new "layer" to be on. When you set the image to absolute, to position it correctly, make the parent of the image relative, then position and resize the image according to the origin of the parent.

Comment: So basically, I just have to use width to make it fit, as the height is good enough?

Comment: Width will change the size of the image - use top: and left: to position the image accordingly.

Comment: okay.. i will do that :) thx

Comment: well.. it works okay, but the image is filling the whole div now. Maybe i should try with one more col-sm-12 inside it.

Comment: Does changing width attribute not work??

Comment: Tada.. now it works 100% ;) added one more div class inside the other then the picture fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's out of alignment!

When you set the image to absolute, it breaks off the flow of the page, and basically creates a new "layer" to be on. You can say it's "absolutely" off the page flow.

When you set the image to absolute, to position it correctly, make the parent of the image relative, then position and resize the image according to the origin of the parent.

Make sure to add another div so it fits inside it! ***winks***

Comment: Done.. will be glad if you could upvote my post again.. i'm knew to this, so be nice :)